# The start button in Windows 10 is not really start, how should instructions describe it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, documentation

The windows "Start" button was really part of Windows XP and it's just an icon in Windows 7 and 10 but most documentation still calls it start button. Is that correct? Is it acceptable?

Specially when we have to select "Run" afterwards and type a command. Again run is from XP and there is no such menu option in later windows.

So if I  have to write instructions for Windows 10 and Windows 7 where I ask user to press the start button, then run and type "cmd" and enter, what should  be the correct language?

Comment: Why not say Windows key + R, then type "CMD"?

Comment: @spikey_richie That does bring the actual run window which is still accessible in Windows 10 as well, good thought but could it be bettered with actual description than asking to use short-cut?

Comment: It’s called the Start Menu on Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound But what about the run? This is no such option in menu after XP?

Comment: Re @spikey_richie 's comment - if you use simple instructions, you really don't need to run the terminology gauntlet... Some users might not even know what the Task Bar is, especially if you are translating to other languages. 'Win/R type cmd' is as simple as it gets & leaves little room for confusion. It's like people still think that to get to Task Manager you have to start with Ctrl/Alt/Delete [then fumble around with menu options]... when Ctrl/Shift/Esc has been a better method since Vista ;)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft removed the word "Start" from the Start menu icon starting with Vista, to presumably give it a cleaner, more modern appearance.

However, if you hover your cursor over the Start menu, you'll still see the tooltip "Start."

[image]

They also still use the same name to refer to this menu in the settings:

[image]

The Run app is also still called "Run" in Windows 10:

[image]

I still refer to them as the "Start menu" and the "Run dialogue box," respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Windows still refers to it as the 'Start Menu', thus it would be correct to say **"On the left end of the taskbar, select the Start icon"** just as Windows themselves instructs:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028294/windows-open-the-start-menu

Comment: When I ceased using Microsoft, task bar was movable to the sides. Can you confirm that's no longer true?

Comment: @uprego: you can still move the Taskbar to the sides or top of the screen in Windows 10.

Comment: This means your answer is wrong. Please rewrite accordingly. :P